# SQL Server objects in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Well, I haven't found exact what I need in similar questions...

What is the quickest way for renaming object/s in DB?

Bulk renaming while keeping dependencies?

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: What objects are you renaming? Where is the list of these objects held (in a temp table) ??

Comment: As pointed out by @Patrick, sp_rename is the quickest way of renaming objects. However if you go to this link, it says it will break dependencies.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use the [sp_rename](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) procedure to rename an object, however you'll need to find all objects that an object depends on, and all objects that depend on an object and change them to reflect the changes. You also need to change code of all external applications, if any that access that table.

If you want to rename stored procedure or a view the sp_rename is [not advisable.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187586.aspx#Prerequisites)

> To rename a view
>
> While you can use sp_rename to change the name of the view, we
>   recommend that you delete the existing view and then re-create it with
>   the new name.

The quickest way to rename an object without breaking dependencies is to use the third party tool. One of them is ApexSQL Refactor. 
You can find the whole procedure for renaming any object in the article: [SQL database refactoring techniques – Rename method](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-database-refactoring-techniques-rename-method/)

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

With `sp_rename` you can [rename object in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) but you are right, they will break dependencies, so that is not the way to go...

There are several (non-free) tools that can do this, and since they are on the market, I think they are there to solve a problem you can't solve yourself (instead of getting a database script and use `Rename all`).

A tool that you could use is [RedGate SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/sql-refactor).